# linking OCaml code with shared library

Tags: haskell, ocaml, ffi

I compiled a Haskell source package implementing an FFI as a (.so) dynamic library. I would like to call the functions exported via the FFI in OCaml. For this I implemented a simple driver file as follows

```
open Quelea.Shim
open Ctypes
open PosixTypes
open Foreign

let readEffects = 
    foreign "readEffects" (ptr char @-> ptr char @-> returning ptr string)

let effects = readEffects "csasc" "saxasxas"

print_list effects

let rec print_list = function 
                [] -> ()
                | e::l -> print_int e ; print_string " " ; print_list l
```

Where readEffects is a function in the Quelea.Shim module of the Haskell source exported via the FFI with the following signature

```
foreign export ccall readEffects :: CString -> CString -> IO (Ptr CString)
```

I tried compiling the file above (main.ml) as follows

```
 ocamlc -dllpath /home/parallels/.cabal/lib/Quelea-0.0.1/ghc-7.6.3 main.ml
```

The directory `/home/parallels/.cabal/lib/Quelea-0.0.1/ghc-7.6.3` contains the library file `libHSQuelea-0.0.1-ghc7.6.3.so`.

I get the error `Error: Unbound module Quelea`. How do I link the library with the driver file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Quelea.Shim` is a module of Haskell.  OCaml is a different language from Haskell and therefore cannot understand Haskell module paths.

I have never tried something like this but possible scenario is:

- Understand how to load Haskell modules and call functions from ordinary C programs.
- Write a small C function to load the Haskell modules you want. Probably it must prepare entry points of Haskell functions for OCaml.
- Call the loader from OCaml